# Joint WPF development via VSTS and Git

Tags: c#, wpf, git, azure-devops

I have a WPF C# application I’ve created using Visual Studio 2013 on my own private development machine.  It uses a SQL Database I have in Azure, and works fine.  I can perform a build and deploy the result to another machine, and it works fine there, too.

Now I want to bring in a second developer, in another city, to add some new features to this WPF app.  In order for us to work jointly, I plan to open a VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services) account, and choose Git for version control.

However, I’ve never used VSTS, nor Git, and I can find no examples of WPF in VSTS, nor any documentation.

My question is this:  Is it practical for multiple programmers, each using Visual Studio 2013, to jointly develop a WPF application using VSTS and Git?

If we had 5 developers, what would be the best way to perform the build?

Comment: WPF is a GUI framework and has absolutely no bearing whatsoever on the kind of version-control software you're using.

Comment: That is exactly what those two things were designed to do... I personally use GitLab for private projects because it is free, but Visual Studio support is a little of a challenge to set up.

Comment: It has nothing to do with WPF , all you have to do is,open `Team Explorer` window(if installed) , it'll show you what required apps you need to install and will provide download option for em..So download and then , from `Team Explorer` window, you can easily create your free team account and sync your work easily :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, as you confirmed is use **Git** as VCS (version control system).

Second thing, decide where you want to host your remote, such as VSTS, github, bitbucket ect.

Considing you are developing your project by VS (WPF C# project), I suggest to hosted your remote git repo in VSTS since you can connect your VSTS git repo with VS directly. Besides, you can use VSTS other features such as CI build and CD deploy your project etc.

For VSTS, you can work up yo five users for free.

Detail steps to manage your project in VSTS git repo as below:

1. Sign up a VSTS account
2. Create a project in VSTS with Git as VCS
3. Connect the VSTS project with VS 2013 and clone

   Team Explorer -> Connect to Team Projects -> Select Team Projects -> Servers -> Add -> input your VSTS account url (https://account.visualstudio.com) -> OK -> input your email and password which used for connecting to your VSTS account -> After authentication -> select the vsts git repo -> connect -> clone the repo.

   [image][image]
4. Config your user name and email address for the first time to use Git

   Team Explorer -> Settings -> Git settings -> input username and email address -> update.
5. Add your project into local git repo

   The cloned repo (local repo) usually located in `C:\Users\username\Source\Repos\reponame`, you just need to copy your project into the local repo's directory.

   **Note:** Since some files (such as output files) don't need to manage into git repo, you can specify these files into a `.gitignore` file, so that these files won't be added into git repo. This is an example [`.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) file you can refer.
6. Commit changes to local repo and push to remote repo

   In Team Explorer -> Changes -> Add All untracked Files -> Then input the commit message -> Commit and Push.

   [image]
   [image]

Now your project is managed in VSTS git repo, and other developers can co-work with you.

Comment: Liu - I will be trying this in a few days, and if it works, I'll certainly come back and mark it as the answer.  Many thanks.

Comment: Do you manage your project in VSTS git repo successfully now?

Comment: Marina - Your screen shots show Team Foundation Server, whereas I chose Git.  The general direction of your post was very helpful.

Comment: For VS2013, the window to connect VSTS and TFS named Team Foundation Server. And you can connect both VSTS and TFS in it.

Comment: My bad. I had switched over to VS 2017 while I was trying to solve the problem.  When I now go back and look at VS 2013, which I had stipulated in this question, I see your screens are exactly correct. Thanks.